# Check if file is changed by an external application

Tags: c#, wpf, filesystemwatcher

I'm creating a kind of file-editor in WPF, what is the best practice to check if a file has been changed outside of my own WPF application? I know I can track files with the `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` but how can I know if they have been changed outside of my own WPF application?

I would like something as in Notepad++, that gives a kind of warning when a file has been modified outside of Notepad++

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you keep track of some properties of the file like the modified date or the content of the file you could determine if the file was changed from outside.

Comment: You know when your app changes a file. Just ignore changes when your app saves or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, How can i just with the content of a file determine if it was changed from the outside? I still need to save changes with my own app so I can't ignore when my app saves. So these are not really solutions for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileSystemWatcher` raises events whether the file is modified by your application or whether it is modified by another application.

Listen for file change events provided by `FileSystemWatcher` and provide the desired feedback like Notepad++.

Each time before your application changes the file, unlisten to `FileSystemWatcher` events, by setting `EnableRaisingEvents = false`, change the file, and then set `EnableRaisingEvents = true` to listen to events again.